# Django belong to field or parents field

Tags: python, django, django-admin, field

I'm using Django 1.6 and trying to make a field as a parent field and this parent field can have several children field?

I make a DB containing a drop down list contains (Computer, Scanner, Printer )
if the user choose a computer , he can added all things related to it such as monitor ..

is it possible to make it with Django?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need you use `ForeignKey` for that task.

#### Example:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Gadget(models.Model):
    """ This is the model where you'll add gadgets like computer, printer, etc. """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Property(models.Model):
    """ This is the model for adding monitor, etc. to the Gadgets models. """
    gadget = models.ForeignKey(Gadget)
    property = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    something_else = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Thank you,but I'm trying to make one Class Assets Like this            AssetsType = (
        ('Printer-Color','Printer-Color'),
        ('Printer-B&W','Printer-B&W'),
        ('Monitor','Monitor'),) Type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=AssetsType)